# How can I handle enabling/disabling toolstrip buttons when form state changes without using a Select Case statement?

Tags: .net, winforms, oop, design-patterns, state

We all know that it's possible to handle enabling/disabling ToolStrip buttons when a form state changes by using `Select Case` statements (VB.NET) or `switch` case statement in C#.

But I remember my teacher said "using these statements is not a correct way when you are developing a software using OOP".

```
Private Sub SetToolStripButtons()
    Select Case formState
        Case FormStates.Normal
            btnSave.Enabled = False
            btnCancel.Enabled = False
            btnNew.Enabled = True
            btnEdit.Enabled = True
        Case FormStates.Edit
           btnSave.Enabled = True
            btnCancel.Enabled = True
            btnNew.Enabled = False
            btnEdit.Enabled = False
        '.....
        '.....
    End Select
End Sub
```

**EDIT: I put a simple code snippet above**

So what would you recommend instead?

Comment: have you got a small example to show?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the code looks like valid. I see no problem in using Select Case.
However, if you have only two states (Normal and Edit), you can improve your code like this:

```
btnSave.Enabled = (formState = FormStates.Edit)
btnCancel.Enabled = (formState = FormStates.Edit) 
btnNew.Enabled = (formState <> FormStates.Edit) 
btnEdit.Enabled = (formState <> FormStates.Edit)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the [state design pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternState.aspx#_self2)?

You would have an abstract class to represent the state `FormState` that would contain a virtual `SetToolStripButtons()` method:

Then each derived implementation of that class is responsible for knowing how to set the visibility of each button (for the given state). For example the `FormStateNormal` class would override the `SetToolsStripButtons` to contain something like this:

```
btnSave.Enabled = True
btnCancel.Enabled = True
btnNew.Enabled = False
btnEdit.Enabled = False
```

There is more to it than just that, but hopefully this should be a good starting point.

Comment: thanks alot could you please send an example of what you pointed it out?

Comment: I would also like to see an example of this applied to this question.  (A year later).

Answer (score 0):

you can store edit mode in Boolean then set enable= this Boolean 
eg: (Set Edit Mode as "True", else set to "False", then call the function)

```
dim isEdit as Boolean

private sub SetToolStripButtons() 
   btnSave.Enabled = isEdit
   btnCancel.Enabled = isEdit
   btnNew.Enabled = Not isEdit
   btnEdit.Enabled = Not isEdit
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is my solution to this:

1. On Item clicked event in the toolstrip control(a Tool Strip button) a   2. Select case is used to identify the button pressed by its text then a 
   lockcode string is passed to the method lockToolStripItems()
2. lockToolStripItems("lockcode") then the method will take care of if by interpreting the parameters passed by converting it to a char array then a
   For loop is executed to lock or unlock the controls, Do note that 1 or 0 are the characters I have used 1= Enabled=true, 0 = .Enable=false. if Unknown character then it returns an error message box, Note that x variable in the in the method has 3 uses, A. a counter in the for statement, B.char array index, C. an tool strip item index

As easy as that in 3 steps, hope this helps.

```
Private Sub ToolStrip1_ItemClicked(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs) Handles mnuStripDeliveryNote.ItemClicked

            Select Case e.ClickedItem.ToString

                        Case "&New"

                            lockToolStripItems("10")

                        Case "&Edit"
                            lockToolStripItems("01")

                    End Select
                End Sub

    Private Sub lockToolStripItems(ByVal mylockCode As String)
                Dim myChar As Char
                For x = 0 To 1
                    myChar = mylockCode.Chars(x)
                    If myChar = "1" Then
                        mnuStripDeliveryNote.Items(x).Enabled = True
                    ElseIf myChar = "0" Then
                        mnuStripDeliveryNote.Items(x).Enabled = False
                    Else
                        MsgBox("Error on parameter" & myChar & "" & x)
                    End If
                Next
            End Sub
```